# Java PDFbox 2.0.25 - After copying fillable fields to another page, browser can see the copied field values but not Acrobat

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a form filling program that takes in a pdf template with rows of fillable fields as well as JSON data for the field values, then populates said values into the form. **If there's more rows than can fit on one page, the page is duplicated and the extra rows are added to the duplicate page.** The page is deep cloned, then the tValues for the page annotations are changed, as well as the page for the annotation, and new fields are created for the new page. **When I open my exported pdf in chrome I can see the field values on the new page, but not in Acrobat.** The pdf can be re-saved from chrome to be opened in Acrobat with the values, but this strips away the fillable fields, and I don't want to make users do a work-around for what's likely developer error, since I don't have an in-depth understanding of the PDF spec.

Below is my code for duplicating the page, I'm hoping someone more generally knowledgeable about PDFs can identify what I'm doing wrong so that I can fix it. I haven't included the other helper functions called at the end, but they will essentially find the correct PDField instance and call setValue() on it.

```
    private void createContent(PDDocument document, JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException {

    final PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    final JSONArray rowsArr = (JSONArray)jsonObj.get("rows");
    final int pages = (int)Math.ceil(rowsArr.size() / 34.0);
    
    if (pages > 1)
    {
        // Add additional pages
        final PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(document);
        final PDPage oldPage = document.getPage(0);

        for (int i=1; i < pages; i++)
        {
            final COSDictionary dupPageDict = (COSDictionary)cloner.cloneForNewDocument(oldPage);
            final PDPage dupPage = new PDPage(dupPageDict);

            final List<PDAnnotation> dupAnnoList = dupPage.getAnnotations();
            for (PDAnnotation anno : dupAnnoList)
            {
                final COSDictionary annoDict = anno.getCOSObject();
                final String oldTStr = annoDict.getString(COSName.T); // Field name, ex: INC0

                // Change annotation to new page and create a field for it
                if (oldTStr.endsWith(String.valueOf(i-1)))
                {
                    // Change page link and add to dupPage
                    anno.setPage(dupPage);
                    dupPage.getAnnotations().add(anno);

                    // Update anno name for new page
                    final String dupTStr = oldTStr.substring(0, oldTStr.length() - 1) + i; // ex: INC1
                    annoDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString(dupTStr));

                    annoDict.setItem(COSName.AP, null);

                    // All the fields should be text fields.
                    COSBase ftBase = annoDict.getItem(COSName.FT);
                    if (ftBase instanceof COSName && COSName.TX == ftBase)
                    {
                        final PDTextField oldField = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField(oldTStr);
                        if (oldField != null)
                        {
                            // Create new field for anno
                            final PDTextField dupField = new PDTextField(acroForm);
                            dupField.setPartialName(dupTStr);
                            dupField.setDefaultAppearance(oldField.getDefaultAppearance());

                            if (anno instanceof PDAnnotationWidget)
                            {
                                dupField.getWidgets().add((PDAnnotationWidget) anno);
                                acroForm.getFields().add(dupField);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Append dupPage before instructions page (which is at the end of the doc)
            final PDPageTree pgTree = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
            pgTree.insertBefore(dupPage, pgTree.get(pgTree.getCount() - 1));
        }
    }
    
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    PDResources resources = new PDResources();
    resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
    acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
    {
        addHeaderInfo(acroForm, jsonObj, i);
        addMainInfo(acroForm, rowsArr, i);
        addFooterInfo(acroForm, jsonObj, i);
    }
}
```

Example output file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/7zu7xxo2fflpdnw/example_out_73130945.pdf/file

Comment: Can you also share an example PDF output of your code that illustrates the issue for analysis?

Comment: I have added an example output PDF at the end of the post which showcases the issue @mkl

Comment: One issue: You iterate over the annotations of `dupPage` and then add each of them to `dupPage` (`dupPage.getAnnotations().add(anno)`) - this causes all those annotations to be present twice in the annotation array of `dupPage` which depending on the viewer has funny effects.

Comment: Another issue: According to the JavaDocs of `getWidgets()` : _The list of widget annotations. Be aware that this list is <i>not</i> backed by the actual widget collection of the field, so adding or deleting has no effect on the PDF document until you call `setWidgets` with the modified list._ Thus, `anno` and `dupField` in the end are disconnected. As you eventually set the value of the fields in the `AcroForm` form definition, you set a value in `dupField` but not in `anno`. Some viewers may associate those objects by their name, but the value of which of those objects is used, may differ.

Comment: Another problem you don't get to deal with yet is that the PDF object underneath `anno` in your file is not merely a widget annotation, it's a widget annotation merged with a field. Thus, if you successfully added `anno` as a child element of `dupField`, you would have a field hierarchy with `dupField` as root field named e.g. `ZN0p1` and a child field `anno` named `ZN0p1.ZN0p1`. I'll try to fix this later this week and write an actual answer unless someone else can do so earlier...